# What's the difference between すべき (subeki) and べき (beki)?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, abbreviations

What's the difference between すべき (subeki) and べき (beki)?

> [すべき (subeki)](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%81%99%E5%8F%AF%E3%81%8D) =  should do; ought to do
>
> [べき](http://jisho.org/word/%E5%8F%AF%E3%81%8D) (beki) = should; must; that one ought to; to be done

Both mean "should", but is there a rule as to when to use one instead of the other?

Here are some examples from my text book:

> *motto sentakushi ga aru beki dato omoimasu.*
>   I think there should be more choice
>
> *Nani o subeki ka wakarimasu yo.*
>   You'll know what to do, I'm telling you.

What's the difference between the two? In the examples above, they seem to perform the same function. So why is one used over the other?

Comment: How did you determine that "both mean 'should'"?  A dictionary lookup should tell you that すべき is essentially する＋べき, no?  Some basic research would improve your questions.

Comment: Did you look in any dictionary? Even WWWJDIC (e.g. jisho.org) has that すべき=する+べき. Once you know this, what is your question?

Comment: @Earthliŋ @Snailplane. I did check in a dictionary, which lists "should do" for  するべき and "should; must;" for べき. So they both mean "should" as stated in my question. But the dictionary doesn't make it clear when to use one over the other (Hence, I put `is there a rule as to when to use one instead of the other?` in my question). How do you know when to use one instead of the other. It's not very clear.

Comment: @Snailplane I have updated my question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

べき is used with a verb in its "dictionary form".

> [verb]べき
> should [verb]

As you can see, べき by itself corresponds to "should", *but it never appears by itself* (just like "should" doesn't appear by itself).

You can easily form examples,

> 食べるべき = should eat
> 行くべき = should go

You only need to remember one additional rule,

> する＋べき → すべき

(About one in twelve times people also use するべき, probably in contexts where する is felt to be used for more than its usual auxiliary function, so don't be surprised if you see it.)

---

So

> [verb]べき = should [verb]
>
> するべき ≒ すべき = should do

In one line, you don't choose between べき and すべき, you only choose a verb to go with べき and if it's する, then it becomes すべき.

Comment: As I understand it, [`する` indicates 'to do'](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/potential). So in my example: `Nani o subeki ka wakarimasu yo.`: Does this use `subeki` because it has the meaning of `to do` (even though `する` doesn't appear in the example) Is that correct?

Comment: Almost. In the example "*nani o subeki ...*" the verb *suru* does appear, but in shortened form, because *suru* + *beki* combines to ***su**beki* (this ***su*** is from *suru*).