# Describing an adjective with "should"

Tags: grammar

I've noticed that some nouns can be described with すべき, as in

> 彼女{かのじょ}はもっと注意{ちゅうい}すべきだった。 (She *should* have been more careful.)

I understand it as

> 彼女{かのじょ}はもっと注意{ちゅうい}するだった。 (She has been more careful.)

being a complete sentence on its own, and the "shouldness" acting as a modifier.

However, if I wanted to say "Her explanation should be precise", modified from,

> 彼女の説明は具体的。("Her explanation is precise")

I'm not too certain how to insert the する into the sentence, so that すべき can act as a modifier in this particular case.

Comment: するだった unfortunately isn’t grammatically. It’s like “was will (do)”

Comment: For your third sentence, add に then すべきだ

Comment: `I've noticed that some nouns can be described with すべき` -- 注意 is a noun, but 注意す(る) is a suru-verb. 注意すべき consists of a verb 注意する + auxiliary べき/べし. These threads might help: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/41607/9831 , https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/25427/9831 , https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/18642/9831

Answer (score 5, accepted):

注意するだった is ungrammatical.

I think you could think of it this way:

> 注意する -- is careful / pay attention
>   注意した -- was careful / paid attention
>   注意す(る)べきだ -- should be careful / should pay attention
>   注意す(る)べきだった -- should have been careful / should have paid attention

---

The *full* sentence would be:

> 彼女の説明は具体的**だ**。

To say "Her explanation *should be* concrete":

> 彼女の説明は具体的**であるべきだ**。

べき follows a verb (eg 食べるべき, 言うべき, やるべき, す(る)べき) and can't directly follow だ.
To use it with an i-adjective 美しい, you say 美し**くあるべき**; with a na-adjective きれいだ, きれい**であるべき**.

---

To rewrite your example using **す**べき without changing the meaning, I'd say...

> 「彼女は具体的に説明す(る)べきだ。」← using the する-verb 「説明する」"explain"
>   *lit.* "She should explain concretely."
>   (or maaybe 「彼女の説明を具体的にす(る)べきだ。」← 「～を…にする」= "make ~ …"
>   "(She/Someone/You?) should make her explanation concrete.")

Comment: Did you write "maaybe" with two 'a'  because you think this options is less good, or was it just a typo (penultimate line of your answer)? Elongating the 'a' sound makes it sound like you are less certain, but I'm not sure if this was deliberate.

Comment: そおですね、maaaybe、「も～～しかしたら」みたいな感じで書きました。